# Ho to make User-defined exceptions work in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE
  v_employee_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
  v_employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 9999;

  -- define user-defined exception
  e_no_employee EXCEPTION;
BEGIN
  SELECT first_name INTO v_employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = v_employee_id;

  IF v_employee_name IS NULL THEN
    -- raise user-defined exception if no data found
    RAISE e_no_employee;
  END IF;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || v_employee_name);

EXCEPTION
  WHEN e_no_employee THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: No data found for Employee ID ' || v_employee_id);
END;
```

I want it to print 'Error: No data found for Employee ID ' || v_employee_id

however, I'm getting

```
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 8
```

Answer (score 2):

You *cought* wrong error.

Sample data:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> select * from employees;

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME
----------- ----------
          1 Littlefoot
       9999
```

Your procedure, modified - added `no_data_found` exception which fires when `select` doesn't return any rows (which is what you wanted). **Your** exception handler is meant for employees whose data exist in a table, but they don't have first name:

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2    v_employee_name employees.first_name%TYPE;
  3    v_employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 9999;
  4
  5    -- define user-defined exception
  6    e_no_employee EXCEPTION;
  7  BEGIN
  8    SELECT first_name INTO v_employee_name FROM employees WHERE employee_id = v_employee_id;
  9
 10    IF v_employee_name IS NULL THEN
 11      -- raise user-defined exception if no data found
 12      RAISE e_no_employee;
 13    END IF;
 14
 15    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Employee Name: ' || v_employee_name);
 16
 17  EXCEPTION
 18    WHEN e_no_employee THEN
 19      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: Employee ID ' || v_employee_id || ' does not have FIRST NAME');
 20    WHEN no_data_found THEN
 21      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Error: No data found for Employee ID ' || v_employee_id);
 22  END;
 23  /
Error: Employee ID 9999 does not have FIRST NAME

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

That's about employee 9999. How about employee 1?

```
SQL> l3
  3*   v_employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 9999;
SQL> c/9999/1
  3*   v_employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 1;
SQL> /
Employee Name: Littlefoot

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Finally, employee that doesn't exist:

```
SQL> l3
  3*   v_employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 1;
SQL> c/1/123
  3*   v_employee_id   employees.employee_id%TYPE := 123;
SQL> /
Error: No data found for Employee ID 123

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```